# Como "gerar" vários clientes TCP usando Threads num mesmo script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, multithreading

Escrevi o código de um cliente TCP simples:

```
from socket import *

# Configurações de conexão do servidor
# O nome do servidor pode ser o endereço de
# IP ou o domínio (ola.python.net)
serverHost = 'localhost'#ip do servidor
serverPort = 50008

# Mensagem a ser mandada codificada em bytes
menssagem = [b'Ola mundo da internet!']

# Criamos o socket e o conectamos ao servidor
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))

# Mandamos a menssagem linha por linha
for linha in menssagem:
    sockobj.send(linha)

    # Depois de mandar uma linha esperamos uma resposta
    # do servidor
    data = sockobj.recv(1024)
    print('Cliente recebeu:', data)

# Fechamos a conexão
sockobj.close()
```

Gostaria de saber como "gerar" vários clientes TCP usando Threads ao invés de eu abrir várias instâncias do terminal e rodar o script várias vezes.

Comment: Você tentou criar uma classe que defina todas essas configurações do socket e implementá-lo usando threads? https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar a thread. Criação de threads no python depende somente de criar uma classe herdando a classe Thread, bem simples, veja o exemplo. https://imasters.com.br/artigo/20127/py/threads-em-python/?trace=1519021197&source=single

No seu caso ficará com algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
from threading import Thread
from socket import *

class ThreadSocket(Thread):

    def __init__ (self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        '''seu código aqui'''

t1 = ThreadSocket()
t2 = ThreadSocket()
t3 = ThreadSocket()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```